# How to check that $\mathbb{Z}_{4} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{4}$ isn't subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{16}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2} $?

Tags: group-theory

Consider two groups $\mathbb{Z}_{4} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{4}$  and $\mathbb{Z}_{16} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ . How to prove that the first one isn't a subgroup of the latter?

I tried to consider some homomorphisms between them (if first one is subgroup then there is a map between them). But I have no success there.
Any hint?

Comment: Well first, how are you even going to make it a subset?

Comment: And if you are willing to take an embedding and not a literal, then examine orders of elements in the second slot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: How many elements of order four does each group have?

Answer (score 3):

There are two subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{16} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ with order 16, $\mathbb{Z}_8 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{16} \oplus \{e\}$. Neither of these will work, since they have elements of order 8 and 16, while $\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$'s elements have orders of at most 4.

Answer (score 1):

Since the order of each element of $\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4$ is less than or equal to $4$, if $\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4$ was isomorphic with a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{16}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$, then the first component of each element of that subgroup could not belong to $\{1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,15\}$ (each of them has order $8$ or $16$). By removing these $24$ elements from $\mathbb{Z}_{16}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$, only $8$ elements remain, which is not enought to form a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4$.